# Downloading file from server

Tags: xml, http, blackberry, download

Here I am trying to download a file from the server onto the sdcard. The code is as shown below:

```
try{
   FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/documents/Report.xml");
   if (fconn.exists()) {
      fconn.delete();
   }

   fconn.create();
   add(new RichTextField("Deleted and created", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));

   HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)        
   Connector.open("http://127.0.0.1/xml/home.xml");
   add(new RichTextField("Connection success", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
   InputStream ds = connection.openInputStream(); 
   byte[] data = new byte[ds.available()];
   ds.read(data);
   add(new RichTextField("Data read", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
   OutputStream outStream = fconn.openOutputStream();
   outStream.write(data);
   outStream.close();
   add(new RichTextField("Data written succesfully", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
   fconn.close();

   }
   catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
}
```

The problem is that on the emulatora I see the first two messages i.e.

- Deleted and created
- Connection success

But after, that no message is given that the data is written or not. The size of XML file is 1KB.
Can please help me over this? Is there any problem in my code or is there another problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this line:

```
add(new RichTextField("Deleted and created", Field.NON_FOCUSABLE));
```

Makes me think you are doing this directly on the event thread, which is bad practice. If the connection times out or takes a long time, then you are freezing the GUI for that time. You would usually spawn a worker thread to do long tasks like this.

That said, your code could work, but it is not really robust. A lot of things can go bad. For instance, this line:

```
HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://127.0.0.1/xml/home.xml");
```

The returned connection can be null so you must check for it. You'd better use `ConnectionFactory` instead as it appends the correct suffix for each kind of connection (WiFi, BES, TCP,...). In simulator, I'm not sure you can use a localhost URL since it is local to your workstation, but the simulated BB device has to go through an MDS simulator.

With `FileConnection` you must also check it is not null, and also that `fconn.canRead` returns true. Take into account that not every device has an sdcard slot (most recent ones do). You could check if the card is available as it is explained in [this article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Programmatically-determine-if-a-microSD-card-has-been-inserted/ta-p/442895), or let the `catch` handle the exception. If you are testing on simulator, you'll have to "mount" a virtual sdcard.

Also this call:

```
ds.read(data);
```

will block until the server actually sends you something. This is probably what is happening.

You must check you have the correct permissions. For the file connection, you'll need:

```
ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_FILE_API
```

And for the network connection, depending on where are you connecting to, you'll need one of:

```
ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_INTERNET
ApplicationPermissions.PERMISSION_SERVER_NETWORK
```

A final tip: add a finally clause to the try-catch, and close all the streams and connections in the finally (in case they are not null).

Comment: Thanks 4 an early reply. I have tested for all the NULL values, my connection is also successful but the problem is at Input Stream object creation. So please give me a solution for the input stream and how to use all permissions that you mentioned above.

Comment: The inputstream line is the first that actually establishes the HTTP connection. Maybe you are having a timeout. You should let it run at least 3 minutes, and also log the exception. Then post it please.

Comment: About the permissions, I think they are not needed in simulator. In real devices, the user sets the permissions at install (or later via the options menu).

Comment: did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: yes first of all there was a connection timeout, also my antivirus (ESET) was blocking the firewall which made my work even more worse.. Thanks for the help Mr. Smith

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP connection is only attempted on the line `InputStream ds = connection.openInputStream();` which is failing so you don't see any messages after that. The reason for the failure is probably because the simulator is unable to get to the specified URL.

On the line `Connector.open("http://127.0.0.1/xml/home.xml");` try changing the URL to `http://127.0.0.1/xml/home.xml?interface=wifi`.

This will force the simulator to use the simulated WLAN connection which is actually your PC's network interface. Ensure that the simulator is connected to `Default WLAN connection`.

Also, rather than adding UI fields to a screen in order to see what's going on in your code, you'd be better off adding debug message (e.g. `System.out.println("Got connection")`) and using the debugger - just press F11 from within eclipse.